# Modifying text within an XML file used within a flash program

Tags: xml, flash

The flash can be seen at http://www.illinoisprocessserver.com titled: new-final.swf. When I make changes to the associated XML file: data.xml the changes do not display.

old XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xtream>
  <select titles="Data Entry/Batch Import" description="Our computerized tracking system imports and exports data in any format. You can use Excel  spreadsheets, fixed-length formats, XML (most powerful) or any other format your firm requires to send and receive data and documents with us." />
  <select titles="Assigned To Field Agent" description="After review, jobs are assigned to the process server." />
  <select titles="Real Time Field Updates" description="In major metropolitan areas, our tracking system is updated immediately with cell phone PDA devices using SOAP and XML calls to our API. In more rural areas, our system is updated within 12 hours of the attempt taking place." />
  <select titles="Reports VIA Website or Email" description="We can provide you with custom statistical reports in addition to our standard ones available on our website." />
  <select titles="View Scanned Documents" description="All proofs of service are scanned and use automatic barcode recognition to automate the process." />
</xtream>
```

New XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xtream>
  <select titles="Data Entry/Batch Import" description="Our computerized tracking system imports and exports data in a variety of formats. (Excel, Fixedlength, XML). We have direct links to multiple interfaces (net director, serve-x, cogent, jst) and can create custom bridges and data links to accommodate our client's needs." />
  <select titles="Assigned To Field Agent" description="Documents are filed and processed internally and placed with field investigator. Internal tracking mechanisms are in place to assure timeliness and efficiency while maintaining quality control." />
  <select titles="Real Time Field Updates" description="Via our secure web application, completion and attempt information is entered in the field real time utilizing GPS tracking. This provides up to date information allowing United to assure and monitor quality control and audit the integrity of the attempts utilizing feasibility reports. Photos are obtained with Date/Time stamps assuring the integrity and accuracy of the information." />
  <select titles="Reports VIA Website or Email" description="We can provide you with custom statistical reports in addition to our standard ones available on our website." />
  <select titles="View Scanned Documents" description="All service documents and affidavits are scanned and uploaded utilizing our bar code recognition software allowing clients access via our secure web portal." />
</xtream>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Clear you catch and check it. You can append the timestamp/random number query with your xml path like,  new.xml+"?rand="+Math.random(0,1000) to get rid of cache and load new xml file every time.